# Javascript regex matching literal \\n

Tags: javascript, regex

Stumbled on this little oddity today, can someone explain?

```
x = 'a \\n b';
x.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>');               // => "a <br> b"
x.replace(RegExp('\\n', 'g'), '<br>');   // => "a \\n b"
x.replace(RegExp('\\n', 'gm'), '<br>');  // => "a <br> b"
```

I assumed `/\\n/g` and `RegExp('\\n', 'g')` would be equivalent, but that doesn't seem to be the case. In what cases will using one method over the other give different results?

Why is the multiline flag needed, and only when using a RegExp object?

EDIT:
3rd replace was me being cross-eyed, that is `x.replace(RegExp( '\\n', 'gm'), '<br>'); // => "a \\n b"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is the multiline flag needed, and only when using a RegExp object?

That is not needed at all. Behaviour of `m` modifier doesn't differ when used with regex literal, and `RegExp` constructor. I don't see how your 3rd replace, give you that output:

```
x.replace(RegExp('\\n', 'gm'), '<br>');  // => "a <br> b"
```

this should give you `"a \\n b"` only. When you use a backslash inside a string literal, you need to escape it. Similarly, you need to escape any escape sequence in your string literal. This means, you need 2 extra backslashes there. 1 for `\n`, and 1 for `\` that is before `\n`.

```
x.replace(RegExp('\\\\n', 'g'), '<br>');
```

However, with regex literal, it isn't like that. You don't need any extra backslash. So, now 1st and 2nd shouldn't give you the same result.

Comment: You are right, that replace didn't give me that output. I apparently just cant read the console. Totally forgot about double escaping, knew it was something simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to double-escape with the RegExp constructor since it's a string, that will be converted to a regex. You can test this:

```
console.log(RegExp('\\n')); //=> /\n/
console.log(RegExp('\\\\n')); //=> /\\n/
```

This applies to any special characters, so `\d` is `\\d`, `\b` is `\\b`, etc.